# How to trim a rendered item before and after specific symbols

Tags: uri, entities

I've created a field where I store the URL to an image. I need to display the filename of the image without the part before the slash and without the file extension.

> http://some.url.com/folder/this/and/that/361.jpg

should be displayed as 361

> http://some.url.com/url/folder/this/and/that/1021.jpg

should be displayed as 1021

I know that this can be handled field--field-name-of-url.tpl.php file but I wasn't able to apply the solutions I've found correctly.

I tried the regex and explode method but I don't know how to insert it into the code below.

Thanks for any help.

```
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item) : ?>
    <?php print render($item); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What's in the $item variable in an iteration of the loop?

Comment: This is what I have as the tpl file to output the single value which is stored in that field. I hope that this is what you asked for.

Comment: if you install the devel module, you can `dpm($item)` inside your foreach loop. That'll tell you where your urls are.

Answer (score 1):

A tip from a friend got it working. Here the solution.

```
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item) : ?>
    <?php 
     $file_extension = substr(render($item) , strrpos(render($item) , '.') +1);
     print basename(render($item), '.'.$file_extension);
    ?>
     </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```